# PowerShell GetAccessControl returns inconsistent results

Tags: powershell, acl

I know the title might be a little misleading but it was impossible to write it better without having to type 10 lines of text, so here I go:

I'm trying to list the permissions of my hard drives and I found that the following approach works pretty good:

```
$drives = get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { ($_.DriveType -eq 3) -and ($_.DriveLetter -ne $null) }; ForEach($drive in $drives) {$drive.DriveLetter; ((Get-Item $drive.Name).GetAccessControl('Access')).Access}
```

Here I explain what each part of the script does:

Store all hard drive entries into $drives

```
$drives = get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { ($_.DriveType -eq 3) -and 
($_.DriveLetter -ne $null) }
```

Cycles through each hard drive instance and prints the hard drive name

```
ForEach($drive in $drives) {$drive.DriveLetter;
```

Prints the ACL permissions given to each drive, by passing $drive.Name as the drive name parameter

```
((Get-Item $drive.Name).GetAccessControl('Access')).Access}
```

Today I noticed something pretty funky... If I execute the command I mentioned before I get an entry with 6 different ACL items, like this one:

```
PS C:\Users\lopezcha> $drives = get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { ($_.DriveType -eq 3) -and ($_.DriveLetter -ne $null) };
 ForEach($drive in $drives) {$drive.DriveLetter; ((Get-Item $drive.Name).GetAccessControl('Access')).Access}
C:


FileSystemRights  : Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

FileSystemRights  : AppendData, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

However, If I pass the drive name directly as text instead of using $drive.Letter, I get only 3 ACL items instead of 6

```
PS C:\Users\lopezcha> ((Get-Item 'C:').GetAccessControl('Access')).Access


FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : AMERICAS\lopezcha
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why this behavior occurs?

EDIT: I found something interesting... If I use "C:" as the drive name, I get 3 ACLs back, but if I use "C:\" I get 6 ACLs. This partially answers my question, but I still would like to know why the difference in the amount of permissions returned.

$drive.DriveLetter = C:
$drive.Name = C:\

Comment: In 2020, PS Version 5, you do not need an argument for `getaccesscontrol()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more simple than you would expect. This is because of the provider. The term `c:` refers to the current folder location that the provider is using on the specified drive. While `c:\` refers to the root folder of that drive.

Let me put this another way to give better reference. Back when I started using computers, and the screens where nothing but green and black, we used floppy disks quite a bit. Now if I wanted to copy some files from a floppy disk to c:\temp what I would do is first change to the temp folder on my hard drive, then change to the floppy drive, and then copy the files to the c: drive. It would look like such:

```
C:\> cd temp
C:\temp> cd a:
A:\> copy *.* c:
```

That would copy all of the files from the a: drive to the last folder I was in on the c: drive.

The same applies here, as when you us `c:` as your reference it is looking at (most likely) the current folder that you are executing the command from.

This would become much more evident if you were not just immediately expanding the 'Access' property, as the base object would have told you the name of the folder that you were looking at the rights for.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I have used DOS and developed software for quite a few years, and I never heard before that C: was actually a reference to the folder were you are executing your command from. Just to prove your point, I tested getting the permissions of the folder I was running the command from "C:\Users\lopezcha" and I got the exact same permissions as if I was using "C:". Thanks for the lesson, I marked your response as the answer to this question.

Regards